# Change root directive in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Now I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule login$ login.html [QSA,L]
RewriteRule password/recovery/reset$ /login.html [QSA,L]
```

In the root folder in my htaccess.  In both cases I have login.html, but in second case all included in login.html scripts and css files are not avaliable (404), because routing is wrong.
`/password/recovery/assets/css/reset.css`, but it should be `/assets/css/reset.css`
How can I change my htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to ensure that your HTML files are referencing the CSS files correctly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/reset.css">
```

See the leading slash before `assets`? That tells the browser to request the file from the root of the domain/project.